# Delegates Program

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I made a very simple program of Delegates. I have no idea why is it showing error, even though I compared it with the one given in MSDN library, its same like the one in MSDN, still not getting compiled..the error says- "The name 'Add' does not exist in the current context "and same for the other method.. Subtract.
Please help me find what is the problem..

```
namespace DelegatePrac
{   
   public delegate void One(int a, int b); 
    public class Some
     {
  static void Add(int a, int b)
       { 
      int c = a + b;    Console.WriteLine("{0}",c);
       }
       static void Subtract(int a, int b)
       { int c = a - b;  Console.WriteLine("{0}",c);
       }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            One o1,o2;
            o1 = Add;//gives error here
            o2 = Subtract;//and here!!
            o1(33,44);
            o2(45, 15);
         Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I was following this link- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should see a compiler message:

> The name 'Add' does not exist in the current context

which tells you that it has no clue which `Add` method you are talking about; `Add` is a static method in `Some` - so you need:

```
o1 = Some.Add;
o2 = Some.Subtract;
```

static methods aren't globally available; you can access static methods from the *current* type (and from base-types) via just their name, but if it is an unrelated type you need to qualify it with the declaring-type.

At this point it will give you a compiler error:

> 'DelegatePrac.Some.Add(int, int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

which hints that it is a *private* method; so add `public` (or `internal`) to them:

```
public static void Add(int a, int b) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks..... but..the documentation in MSDN says something else only... I was following that..!! This truly solved the purpose!! :)

Comment: @Novice in the MSDN example all the methods are in the same type - see my "you can access static methods..." sentence. This is also why the MSDN example can access them even though they are private (you can access private methods inside the same type).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried exchanging those two lines with errors with this?

```
o1 = Some.Add;
o2 = Some.Subtract;
```

You haven't posted your error, but the class Program has no `Add` or `Subtract` methods, so I guess your error is that `Add` and `Subtract` is not found.

**EDIT**

And as ssd said in his answer, the static methods have to be `public` to be accessed from outside the class. You have not specified any access modifier, and thereby the methods will default to `private`.

Comment: @Øyvind : I did post error in my post in inverted commas! I got confused because of the MSDN library..!!!

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- You need to mark `Add` and `Subtract` as `public`.
- They are not part of `class Program`. So while using them in other classes than `Some`, you need to specify they are part of `Some` by using `Some.Add` and `Some.Subtract`.

### Corrected Code:

```
namespace DelegatePrac
{   
    public delegate void One(int a, int b); 
    
    public class Some
    {
        public static void Add(int a, int b)
        { 
            int c = a + b;    Console.WriteLine("{0}",c);
        }
       
        public static void Subtract(int a, int b)
        { 
            int c = a - b;  Console.WriteLine("{0}",c);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            One o1,o2;
            o1 = Some.Add;//gives error here
            o2 = Some.Subtract;//and here!!
            o1(33,44);
            o2(45, 15);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```